# Is there any way to download image from web in qml

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I need to download images from a web and store it in device. Is it possible in only qml and js? without using c++.

Comment: Pure QML as well as js usually has no access to a file system. But you always can extend it with custom item/plugin written in C++/Qt.

Answer (score 0):

Standard QML do not have access to filesystem. You can use websockets in pure QML (but they are created for text-like format) but no save on local storage.
But you can do it only partial in C++. QML is east extendable by C++. Just write required functionality in C++ and invoke this in QML-lvl like standard js function, please find this document:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-overview.html

You can try just register QFile to QML system without write you own class. I think it couldn't work out of box (but QFile is QObject, so...).